# how to query active record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm

I want to see which of my students have certificates. In the Student model `has_many :certifications` . When I do the `Student.where(company_id:79).count` or the `Student.where(company_id:79).all` query it returns both the number of students (which are 748) and an array with all students. However, I can only consult if there are certificates, one by one per Student. When I do `Student.where(company_id:79).certifications` it returns an error: `(undefined method "certifications" for #<Student::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000564640516fd0>)`

And when I do `x = Student.where(company_id:79).last` and
`x.certifcations` then yes it returns the student's certificate or not.

Comment: You have to use [joins](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins). `Student.where(company_id:79).joins(:certifications)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have one to many association between student and certificate, you can do it this way:
`Student.where(company_id: 79).joins(:certificates).distinct`